# Unable to shorten a specific prompt's PATH in Zsh

Tags: zsh

I run unsuccessfully the following [code](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-z.html) at /usr/local/bin

```
LBIN=/usr/local/bin
```

**How can you change specific prompt's PATHs in Zsh?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After setting

```
LBIN=/usr/local/bin
```

Try cd-ing to it:

```
$> cd ~LBIN
```

And see what the prompt shows you.

If you want this behavior by default, set LBIN in your zshrc.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I did not know that you need the tilde.